Ecuador: state of emergency and safety in Guayaquil
There was this year 30-Day Extension of Nationwide State of Emergency in Ecuador, declared in March.
Then it was transformed into 60 days Sate of Emergency declared in seven provinces and one canton through July 20. According to Czech embassy (I'm sorry, just in Czech) it's not recommended to go to Guayaquil and Esmeraldas cities.
I was considering to fly from Guayaquil to Lima, is it safe? Or should I instead go to Quito and fly from there? What transport should I avoid in Ecuador due Sate of Emergency?

It is unfortunate that things have escalated to this level but Ecuador is not a war zone either. People have to be very cautious but they go about their day. There is no way to know how much worse things will get which is why there are travel advisories issued for the country.
If you were considering visiting Guayaquil, then you should change your plans. The center, which is the most interesting area, to visit is considered very dangerous now. However, if the plan is simply to transit through the Guayaquil  Airport, to save money, then I don't expect it be unsafe. Should your flight require an overnight stay, then you could go to the Holiday Inn which is near the airport. You can request a shuttle service which will be safer than going there on your own. I don't know if this is still the case but the shuttle was free.
State of emergencies are volatile and so you should be frequently read updates about the situation. To get more accurate info, I suggest you read one of the online news sites from Ecuador and use Google Translate, if you don't understand Spanish.
